# Getting the Restify Handler Object using "this"

Tags: node.js, restify

I set up a Restify route using the following code.  I create a pseudoclass, instantiate the object and use that as the handler.  I want the object itself to be bound to "this" in the "ping" function so I have access to the member variables.  However, "this" ends up pointing to some restify object that contains routes, etc.  Is this something that just won't work with Restify?

```
    var Handler1 = function() {
       if (!(this instanceof Handler1 )) {
        return new Handler1 ();
       }
       ...
    }
    HttpHandlers.prototype.ping= function(req, res, next) {
            //this doesn't point to the handler1 object.
            return next();
     }
...
    var myhandler1 = new Handler();
    app.get("/ping", myhandler1.ping , handler2);
    handler1.ping.bind(myhandler1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try giving an object instance as the route instead of the object.  That makes bit more sense to me.

```
class Pong1 {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  ping = res => res.write(`PONG ${this.name}`);
}

const pong1 = new Pong1('Pongy);
app.get('/ping', pong1.ping);
```

This is more like an ES2017 version, which I think is preferable.  You should be able to convert to a more ES5 syntax if you really want.

Comment: @"Jason Livesay", in my attempt to simplify the code when posting her, I removed the ".ping".  I have to use the older syntax for now until we do a code cleanup later.  So I'm still not sure why I'm not getting the context.

Comment: If you are checking that 'this' is bound in the `.prototype.ping` maybe thats the problem, because you did not bind the prototype function, instead you bound the function on the instance created after.

Comment: "Jason Livesay", So I tried adding .bind(Pong1 ) on the function declaration.  When I inspect "this" I see the object/pseudoclass now, but it doesn't look like it contains the object instance variables.  What I'm trying to do is have a way to instantiate a "class" and for its function to have access to the object's member variables set up in the constructor.

Comment: Well, there are a ton of ways to do it, but the way I demonstrated is the only way I can currently recommend.  I really recommend not doing it a different way because it is generally confusing for everyone having to figure out different types of OOP in JS and because it makes it harder for you.  I know adding babel is a huge deal though.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I needed to pass in the bound function:

```
app.get("/ping", myhandler1.ping.bind(myhandler1), handler2);
```